# How can I set image in textDocumentProxy with custom keyboard extension iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, custom-keyboard

How can we set an image behalf of the text?

Following code is to display text in the input view:

```
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[key currentTitle]];
```

My code of paste board to display the image :

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[pasteBoard setData:imgData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[pasteBoard string]];
```

I have created a pasteboard with the images just I have to display the images in to input view.

See this picture for the concept :

[image]

### Note:

**I have to select image from keyboard and show in inputview not to copy paste from library.**

If anyone know please reply as answer or any suggestion will also acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: Where do u take the images to load??

Comment: How could you convert the NSdata into the string? For my case, it is showing nil when I convert that NSdata into the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have get solution for this question use clipboard copy and paste

**Code :**

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSData *data = [self.Videoassets objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
NSLog(@"File size is : %.2f MB",(float)data.length/1024.0f/1024.0f);
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.mpeg-4"];
```

Comment: first of all you have choose image into galley and clipboard copy paste function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81271/discussion-between-rohit-suvagiya-and-hardik-vyas).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to add directly an image from a custom keyboard. A workaround would be to copy the image to the pastboard and paste it in the destination area. (It's not very nice but It's the only way I see actually)

Comment: i will select image in keyboard and show inputview not copy paste

Comment: why ? it is not possible ? .. it is right ans i have tried this at my home it will work.